# Browser in IOS devices doesn't auto play sound in background

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js

I have coded a small web page. I need to play audio sound in background when opening first site. In Window browser or Android browser work perfectly, but in IOS browser it done't work at all.
so does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible due to security reasons. User have to interact with the website before playing a background sound and also the tab should be focused when playing the file.